# Schatten norm when the product of the support projections is 0

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm reading a paper that uses the following result: let $A \geq 0$ and $B \geq 0$ be elements of $B(H)$ ($H$ is a Hilbert space, and $B(H)$ is the space of bounded operators on $H$). If $s(A)$ and $s(B)$ are the support projections of $A$ and $B$, respectively, and $s(A)s(B) = 0$, then for every $1 < p < \infty$ we have
$$\|A + B\|_p^p = \|A\|_p^p + \|B\|_p^p$$
where $\|\cdot\|_p$ is the Schatten p-norm.

Can someone give a proof of this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If either $A$ or $B$ is not compact, both sides of your equality are infinity and so the equality holds.

Assume $A,B$ are compact. By the Spectral Theorem
$$
A=\sum_n\alpha_n\,P_n,\qquad B=\sum_m\beta_m\,Q_n,
$$
where $P_1,P_2,\ldots$ are pairwise orthogonal and same for the $Q_m$. By removing terms if necessary, we may assume that $\alpha_n>0$ for all $n$, $\beta_m>0$ for all $m$. Since
$$
(A^*A)^{1/2}=\sum_n \alpha_n \,P_n,\qquad (B^*B)^{1/2}=\sum_m \beta_m \,Q_n
$$
we have that
$$
\sigma_n(A)= \alpha_n ,\qquad\sigma_m(B)= \beta_m .
$$
Also,
$$
s(A)=\sum_nP_n,\qquad s(B)=\sum_mQ_m. 
$$
Thus the condition $s(A)s(B)=0$ translates to $P_nQ_m=0$ for all $n,m$. This implies $AB=BA=0$.
Then
$$
|A+B|=A+B=\sum_n\alpha_nP_n+\sum_m\beta_mQ_m
$$
and so the singular values of $A+B$ are $\{\alpha_n\}\cup\{\beta_m\}$. Finally,
$$
\|A+B\|_p^p=\sum_n\alpha_n^p+\sum_m\beta_m^p=\|A\|_p^p+\|B\|_p^p. 
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!